# Calculating (n ^ fibonacci(k)) MOD m for a large value of k

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

The value of $k$ can be very large indeed (up to $10^{12}$). Is there an efficient way to calculate the output?

Edit : 'm' is a prime number.

Comment: If you know the factorization of $m$ maybe compute `fibonacci(k) mod something` fast?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming $n$ and $m$ are coprime and $m$ is factored, first compute $a=\text{fibonacci}(k) \mod \varphi(m)$. Computing linear recurrence efficiently modulo $n$ is possible, e.g. via matrix exponentiation.

Then your expression is equal to $n^a \mod m$ which is easy to compute efficiently
working $\mod m$ and fast exponentiation.

$\varphi$ is [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient).

---

If the factorization of $m$ is unknown and $k$ is sufficiently
large, I suspect the problem is quite hard.

Comment: Actually m is a prime number. I forgot to mention it on my problem description. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: @KhazhakKeghartSahak nice, m prime is easier.